# Sort Data in Sheet B when Sheet A Changes Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have three sheets in one workbook in excel. I have Sheet A where I paste raw data from another program, Sheet B that takes the data from Sheet A and sorts the first three columns, and Sheet C that uses the sorted data to do calculations.

What I would like to do is trigger the sort in Sheet B when I paste data in Sheet A, that way if everything was working you would never have to look at Sheet B.

I'm not very experienced with Excel VBA but here is what I've gotten from doing some research:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Application.EnableEvents = False
      Range("A1:C314").Sort _
   Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
     Key2:=Range("B2"), Order2:=xlDescending, _
        Key3:=Range("C2"), Order3:=xlDescending, _
     Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
     Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
     Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

I have this in "Microsoft Excel Objects" in "Sheet B" in the VBA window. The issues I'm having is the macro triggers when I make a change on any sheet, not just Sheet A. What I was trying to accomplish was when I pasted data in Sheet A, the changes in Sheet B would trigger the macro.

Comment: Your code should be in Sheet A, since that's the sheet you expect the changes to happen on. Then, the reason it's not likely doing anything, is you didn't tell it what sheet to actually sort on.  Without doing that, it's going to use SheetA's `Range("A2")`, etc.  Add `Sheets("SheetB")` before the `.Range(...` parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Worksheet_Change event in SheetA instead of the global Worksheet_Calculate.

Monitor a cell or a range of cells that will be affected when you paste data, for example to monitor column A for changes and run the rest of the code only when a cell in column A is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then

' run code to copy the data from SheetA to SheetB
' run code to sort SheetB

End If

End Sub
```